# Socket.io 1.x - how to constrain emitted message size for websockets

Tags: node.js, websocket, limits, socket.io-1.0

I've searched a lot but found no solution. I want to limit emitted message size for websockets and NOT for HTTP transport. Socket.io has `maxHttpBufferSize` but it limits only the buffer of HTTP transports.

here is clientside code

```
    socket.emit('someevent', somedata);
```

and serverside code

```
    socket.on('someevent', function(data){
       // do something with data
    });
```

I want to reject the connection if "sizeof(somedata)">N kb. Checking should be done before all data is received.